# How to count min max avg of a specific column value and store it in a new column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to the Spark/Scala so I am having many question one of them is. I have a dataframe which contains code, description, depdelay. The column code has repetitive values example(EA) I want the distinct value of code and min,max,avg of depdelay in new columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So as far as i understand, you want to know the min,max,avg for each value in column code. If this is correct, the below steps will help you help in achieving this

1. Using groupby function on column code, it will remove duplicates and group the value of other rows which are having same value in code.
2. No using this grouped data, we can do operation and find the min,max,avg values
   please check below syntax.

```
result=df.groupBy("code").agg(min($"depdelay").alias("min"),max($"depdelay").alias("depdelay"),avg($"depdelay").alias("avg"))
```